# Not sure how to setup CNAME to work with Heroku SSL on www.mydomain.com

Tags: heroku, dns, cname

I've setup a SSL certificate w/ the common name, etc. as 'www.biglikeco.com'. I have set 1 cname in my dns to goto the main Heroku app area - what should the other CNAME record be? I I'm trying to get SSL working on 'www.biglikeco.com' also - is this possible (e.g. https://www.biglikeco.com as well as http://www.biglikeco.com) ?

Thanks.

Comment: I voted to close because I figured it out - JUST MAKE ONE CNAME RECORD WHICH POINTS TO YOUR SSL ENDPOINT eg myapp-1233.herokussl.com).

Comment: That is true for Heroku, but don't you think this information is valuable for others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSL certificates are usually associated with an IP address, not a DNS record.

You need to associate the SSL certificate with your IP on the configuration of your web server.  If you don't have an IP address dedicated to hosting the secure version of your site, you can rely upon Server Name Indication.  Server Name Indication is an extension to the SSL certificate authentication process, such that the domain name AND the IP address are sent to your web server.  DNS (and CNAME records) are not involved in this process, other than the initial name resolution.

Update:
You don't need a second IP address to host a secure version of your site.  You can configure your web server to respond to HTTP and HTTPS separately.  However, the SSL certificate is still strongly associated with your IP address.  It cannot be redirected with a CNAME in DNS.